# Is there any way to deactivate Magento shop and use it only as a catalog?

Tags: catalog, shopping-cart

Is there any way to deactivate Magento's Shoping functionality such as "Add to cart", cart etc. and use Magento only as a catalog?

I'm using Magento 1.9.

Thanks

Comment: please see this url for help
[disable checkout in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165218/disable-entire-cart-functionlity-checkout-in-magento2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to disable magento online sales functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840441/how-to-disable-magento-online-sales-functionality)

1. Disable the onepage checkout in the configuration In

> System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Disable Onepage Checkout.

2. Remove add to cart button logic in

> template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Just delete that functionality.  Without a way to access the cart or add to it the user will not be able to realize there was / is underlying functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm new in Magento world and not sure what you mean with deleting the functionality. How can I do it?