# Disable entire cart functionality & checkout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, sales

From the admin side I can disable the one step checkout, but still users can add products to the cart. I want to display only products without checkout.
Is there any extension there?
I mean disable mini cart, add to cart links on the entire site.

Where can I customize through plugins or observers or rewrite (mostly in single shot) so that it will hide add to cart links everywhere.
By editing `list.phtml` I can do this. But is there any better way?

Comment: You can follow this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840441/how-to-disable-magento-online-sales-functionality

Answer (score 7):

Please try it
**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="module-filter" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

</config>
```

in **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Product
{               
    public function afterIsSaleable(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {           
            return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Now 'In stock ' text is coming.So anyway i need to use css to hide?

Comment: Yes, add css any where

.stock {
    display: none;
}

Comment: You can also update all your product with Qty = 0 ?

Answer (score 6):

There are lot of works need to do this  question:
Here  the steps:

### 1.Disable Checkout module block output

***This case, you disable checkout module block output that make Cart/Checkout blank*** and  also will remove minicart pop,So Customer cannot place order place.

*disable module  `Magento_Checkout` output from Admin*.Just to `admin>Store>Configuration>Advance>Advance`.

There are lot of thing,you need do this case.

For this case, you may be need below steps:

- Disable Checkout module block output using Magento default  System
  setting

Then Select the module **Magento_Checkout** Change it status to **`Disabled`** and after that click on **Save Config** button for save the setting.

[image]

### 2.Disable some blocks output using plugin which have AddtoCart button

In case,idea is **disabled output of block** those block which  generate add to cart to block using [**plugin**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

As you know that  from  class [**Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L647) ` **toHtml()** output of **block is generated**

In my plugin, **find some blocks(`Which are generate Add to Cart button`) name in layout like**:

- [product.info.addtocart](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L65)
- [product.info.addtocart.additional](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml#L79)
- [product.info.addtocart.bundle](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml#L20)

**di.xml create is app\code[Vendorname][Module]\etc\frontend**

,So ***it will only work frontend not for admin***.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
        <plugin name="disabledOutofAddtoCartblock" type="[Vendorname]\[Module]\Plugin\AbstractBlockPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin class ***AbstractBlockPlugin*** located at a`pp/code/[Vendorname]/[Module]/Plugin/`.

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[Module]\Plugin;

class AbstractBlockPlugin{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ){

          $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
    * Using after method change  return value of toHtml
    */
    public function afterToHtml(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $block ,$result){

       $moduleName = $block->getModuleName();
       $nameInLayout = $block->getNameInLayout();

       $_disableBlocksNameInLayout = array(
            'product.info.addtocart','product.info.addtocart.additional','product.info.addtocart.bundle',

        );
       /** 
       * If block name is match then return Blank
       */
       if(in_array($nameInLayout ,$_disableBlocksNameInLayout)){
           return "";
       }
       return $result;
    }

}
```

Then require a cache:flush magento  shell using `bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: ,Magento 2.2 disable module output feature won't be there.